# Limit foreach loop with condition

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

this question already asked many times but I am unable to find a solution for my problem. My php knowledge is very limited.

I am building a wordpress website where there a custom taxonomy called "series". This website will have many series and I am using a custom field for grouping series. So it will be easy to organize series on frontend in groups.

So here the code for showing 'series' (https://pastiebin.com/5b445ae944a13):

```
<?php $x = 0; foreach ( $new_mod_series as $cat ): ?>

   <?php $seriestype = get_field( "series_type", $cat ); ?>

   <?php while ( $seriestype == "interview" and $cat_post->have_posts() ): $cat_post->the_post(); ?>

      Show interview series...

   <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (++$x == 5) break; endforeach; ?>
```

This code `<?php $seriestype = get_field( "series_type", $cat ); ?>` don't run outside of foreach loop and with this I can get value of 'series type' custom field. Then I am using `$seriestype == "interview"` in while to show only series which are interview.

And now I am not getting expected or 5 foreach results because limiting only 'interview' series to show. But I need to show 5 recent interview series in a section, then other 5 series of another series section.

Is there anyway to solve my problem? With my limited php knowledge, I tried a lot but could not found any solution. Hopefully I was able to explain correctly.

Thanks
Julash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not query by the custom field? So that you don't have the same query twice (which even now can be used only once). See the acf documentation here regarding your issue https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

In short:

`new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'series',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $cat->term_id,
            )
            ),
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'series_type',
                'value'   => $mod_series,
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
        )
    )
);`

**Edited Answer Based on request**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this doesn't solve my problem. Because this Query is running inside the foreach loop. So I will not get expected foreach loop limit only for a series type I am looking.

Comment: see my edited answer above, basically you run that outside the foreach for the category, yet the $mod_series array should only have category id's, not the whole category object. Or make another array containing only the category ids and use that in the value.

Comment: Thanks again. Your updated code helped and It's working now. But running 'new WP_Query' outside the loop was not working properly. Then after adding 'meta_query' from your code in the first query of 'get_terms' its working. Check whole updated code here https://pastiebin.com/5b445ae944a13

Comment: @Julash I told you that the `$mod_series` array has to contain **ONLY** id's of the category, not the category object. In the first foreach you make, where you build your newmodseries array, simply make another array that only have the id's of the terms and use that in the wp_query. That will make it work outside of the foreach loop. Please pay attention and don't hurry.

Comment: I did pay attention. Problem is I have very basic knowledge of php and don't know how to make another array to have only id's. Really sorry for my lack of knowledge. Really hoping to get better with php soon.

For now I am only tweaking things a little on this theme module here  https://demo.mekshq.com/vlog/?page_id=425. This module only shows selected or all category/series.

With your kind help, now managed to group series by acf field and only 4 result like needed. Here is the result https://unsee.cc/f073fa5a/